# Iphone Application is automatically connected to Facebook and Twitter

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook, twitter

I have a `Objective-C` code and it is connecting to `twitter` and `facebook` automatically. (for example if iphone has a twitter application and application connected to twitter, my application doesn't ask username and password, it is connecting automatically) and customer doesn't want this feature.

I didn't write this this code and unfortunately my `objective-c` and `XCode` knowledge is really very bad :(

Can you give me an idea which why the code is connected automatically and how can I cancel this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is it connected to it? Which feature?

Answer (score 0):

I think in Setting of iphone check Facebook & twitter App. There you entered username & password. If you logout from there then try to post something from your app on Facebook or twitter .It will ask for Login. Before that first search for "**SLComposeViewController**" in your code. If this is there then remove it. Then try. Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  There is no SLComposeViewController in my code :(

Comment: Now.. what it show ? Also you checked for SLComposeViewController in your code?